# Calculating Total Number of Times of Loops

Tags: math, loops, time, complexity-theory

I'm trying to calculate the total number of times the innermost statement is executed.

```
count = 0;
for i = 1 to n
    for j = 1 to n - i
       count = count + 1
```

I figured that the most the loop can execute is O(n*n-i) = O(n^2). I wanted to prove this by using double summation but I'm getting lost since the I'm having trouble starting the equation since j = 1 is thrown into there.

Can someone help me explain this to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each `i`, the inner loop executes `n - i` times (`n` is constant). Therefore (since `i` ranges from `1` to `n`), to determine the total number of times the innermost statement is executed, we must evaluate the sum

```
(n - 1) + (n - 2) + (n - 3) + ... + (n - n)
```

By rearranging the terms (grouping all the `n`s that appear first), we can see that this is equal to

```
n*n - (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n) = n*n - n(n+1)/2 = n*(n-1)/2 = n*n/2 - n/2
```

---

Here's a simple implementation in Python to verify this:

```
def f(n):
    count = 0;
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for _ in range(1, n - i + 1):
            count = count + 1
    return count

for n in range(1,11):
    print n, '\t', f(n), '\t', n*n/2 - n/2
```

Output:

```
1   0   0
2   1   1
3   3   3
4   6   6
5   10  10
6   15  15
7   21  21
8   28  28
9   36  36
10  45  45
```

The first column is `n`, the second is the number of times that inner statement is executed, and the third is `n*n/2 - n/2`.